# python threading.Event: add event params

Tags: python, multithreading

Can I use Event object from threading module not only to notify that some event has happened but also to give some params of this event, for example:

```
e = Event()
...
e.param = "this is event data"
e.set()
```

Another thread:

```
e.wait()
data = e.param
```

It seems to be ok at first glance, but are there any problems than can happen? Is it safe? If not, what other way is better to pass some events params between threads?

Thanx.

Comment: As a side note, it sounds like you're probably trying to use an `Event` as a `Condition`.

Comment: This only works once unless you have other logic to control when param can be read/written. A Queue may be a better choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need to attach the value to the `Event` object, you can just use some other global, attribute, etc. separate from the `Event`, and use the `Event` to signal that it's been updated. And that's the usual way of doing things.

But there's really nothing *wrong* with what you're doing. And it doesn't add any other problems beyond the usual race problems with using events for signaling. However, it does seem a bit misleading—it makes it seem as if the `param` is somehow synchronized, when it isn't.

If you're trying to signal that a new value is ready, and synchronize access to that value you almost always want a `Condition`, like this:

```
c = Condition()
data = None
...

with c:
    data = "new data"
    c.notify()

...

with c:
    while data is None:
        c.wait()
```

Or, more simply, just use a `queue` and don't share a variable in the first place:

```
q = Queue()

...

q.put(data)

... 

data = q.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem with this approach is that if the event is being set rapidly, the param can be overwritten before the waiting thread reads the older value.

A more standard approach for such inter-thread message-passing is using [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).  However, the limitation with a queue-based solution is that only one thread can read the message. In other words: the reader *consumes* the message. This approach is ideal for producer-consumer paradigms. (You didn't mention whether you have multiple threads waiting on the event).

For multiple reader-threads, you should also consider a [pubsub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSub) (publisher/subscriber) solution, although I am unaware of any out-of-the-box pubsub implementation in python.

Comment: No, multiple threads can read a queue. Thread pools can be implemented easily with a single queue.

Comment: Actually in my case every event is used only one time (it means that it is being set only one time)